# Conditional transition probabilites

Tags: probability, markov-process, transition-matrix

I  am confusing myself with a problem which I give below. Can someone please comment and point out my mistakes.

Say I have a two state system  $S_1$ and $S_2$ the probability to transition to the two state (starting from state $S_1$) is $P_1$ and $P_2$. Note $P_1 + P_2 =1$.

In order to model this I assume that there are two independent random numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ following standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$ that trigger the transition i.e. I create a random number $r$ defined as:

$r = a\times r_1 + \sqrt{(1-a^2)} \times r_2$

where both   $r_1, r_2 \sim N(0,1)$ and $a$ is some correlation.
For the two state system whenever $P(r> r_0) > P_2$ we have a transition to the state $S_2$ or else we stay at state $S_1$.

We can also compute the probability of transition to state $S_2$ conditional on generating a random number $r_1$. This conditional probability can be computed as follows:

$P(transition \ to \ S_2| r_1) = N(\frac{N^{-1}(P_2) -a\times r_1}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} ) $

and

$P(staying \ at \ S_1| r_1) = 1 - P(transition \ to \ S_2| r_1)$.

The formulation takes care of the normalization of the conditional probabilities i.e

$P(staying \ at \ S_1| r_1) + P(transition \ to \ S_2| r_1) = 1$

Now say I have a 3 state system (and the same two underlying random variable triggering the transition) for which I can compute:

$P(transition \ to \ S_2| r_1) = N(\frac{N^{-1}(P_2) -a\times r_1}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} ) $

$P(transition \ to \ S_3| r_1) = N(\frac{N^{-1}(P_3) -a\times r_1}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} ) $

and

$P(staying \ at \ S_1| r_1) = 1 - P(transition \ to \ S_2| r_1) - P(transition \ to \ S_3| r_1)$.

With this 3 state situation I am running into computational and intuitive issue which I explain below now:

Say I have a small $P_2 = P_3 = 0.45$ i.e. high probability of transition and probability to stay at $S_1 = 0.1$.

Also say I am trying to to compute $P(transition \ to \ S_2| r_1)$ and $P(transition \ to \ S_3| r_1)$ for a very small $r_1=-5$. Let us also choose $a=0.5$.

Then based on the way I am computing $P(transition \ to \ S_2| r_1)$ and $P(transition \ to \ S_3| r_1)$ above I get

$P(transition \ to \ S_2| (-5)) = N(\frac{N^{-1}(0.45) -a\times (-5)}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} )  = N(3.165) = 0.9992$

$P(transition \ to \ S_3| (-5)) = N(\frac{N^{-1}(0.45) -a\times (-5)}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} ) = N(3.165) = 0.9992$

Now you see that I made a reasoning mistake somewhere which is causing

$P(transition \ to \ S_2| (-5)) + P(transition \ to \ S_3| (-5)) > 1$

and I am unable to figure out my mistake.

It would be very kind if someone can comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have probably missed something but what is your goal when you introduce $r_1$ and $r_2$? Why do you want to introduce these two variables in the first place?

Comment: yes $P_1$, $P_2$ , ... etc. are probability numbers given to me at the first place. I want to model the system in a way that those probabilities are originating from two source of randomness $r_1$ and $r_2$ each of which are standard normal. That is my modelling choice.

Comment: to give a example. Say I have a two state system : 20% of probability of rain and 80% probability of not rain. To model, as a choice, I can think of a hidden random variable $r_1$ distributed normally. When $P(r_1<r_0) <= .20$. As a part of the modelling, I can conclude that $r_0$ is the boundary below which if I generate random numbers it will not rain.

Comment: You have two random variables $r_1$ and $r_2$ whose values are drawn from $N(0,1)$ and you define another random variable $r = a \times r_1 + \sqrt{(1-a^2)} \times r_2$. Now assume you have two probabilities $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that $P_1 + P_2 = 1$, your goal is to find the threshold $r_0$ such that $P(r \leq r_0) = P_1$. You can then generate some values $r$ and compare them to $r_0$ to determine if the state changes or not. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: You understood correctly. I have a little more complexity because I am computing conditional probabilities (which I have described in the main text). But essentially you got it. I have no problem in performing the computations when I have just two states and two probabilities $P_1$ and $P_2$. My mistake arises when I try 3 states and work with 3 probabilities $P_1$, $P_2$,$P_3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a solution to your problem as I understand it. Your main mistake was that you only considered one threshold when dealing with more than 2 states. For the sake of readability I start with the 2 states problem and then address the general case with $n$ states.

---

Let $S_1,S_2$ be two states, $P_1$ the probability of staying in $S_1$ and $P_2$ the probability of moving from $S_1$ to $S_2$ (with $P_1 + P_2 = 1$). In the following we assume that we are in the state $S_1$.

We define $$r=a\times r_1 + \sqrt{(1-a^2)}\times r_2$$
where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are two random variables which follow a standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. Note that, since $a$ is a constant, $r$ also follows a standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$.

Let $r_0$ be the threshold such that $$P(r \leq r_0) = P_1 \text{ and } P(r > r_0) = P_2\text{.}$$
Note that $r_0$ is the solution of the equation $\Phi(x) = P_1$ where $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

Let $b$ be a constant. We can now compute
\begin{align}
P\left(\left.\text{transition to $S_2$} \right| r_1=b\right) &= P\left(\left.r > r_0 \right| r_1=b\right) \\
&= P\left(\left.a\times r_1 + \sqrt{(1-a^2)}\times r_2 > r_0 \right| r_1=b\right) \\
&= P\left(\left.r_2> \frac{r_0 - a\times r_1}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} \right| r_1=b\right) \\
&= P\left(r_2> \frac{r_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}}\right) \\
&= 1- P\left(r_2 \leq \frac{r_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}}\right) \\
&= 1- \Phi\left(\frac{r_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}}\right)\text{.}
\end{align}

---

We now assume that we have $n$ states $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n$. Let $P_i$ be the probability of moving from $S_1$ to $S_i$, such that $\sum_{i = 1}^n P_i = 1$.

We define $r$ as above and we are now looking for several thresholds $r^{i}_0$ with $1\leq i\leq n-1$ such that
$$P(r \leq r^{1}_0) = P_1 \text{, } P(r^{i-1}_0 < r \leq r^{i}_0) = P_i \text{ and } P(r^{n-1}_0 < r) = P_n.$$
Note that $r^{1}_0$ is the solution of the equation $\Phi(x) = P_1$ where $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution and the other thresholds can be similarly computed by first noticing that $P(r^{i-1}_0 < r \leq r^{i}_0) = P(r \leq r^{i}_0) - P(r \leq r^{i-1}_0)$.

Let $b$ be a constant. We can now compute
\begin{align}
P\left(\left.\text{transition to $S_i$} \right| r_1=b\right) &= P\left(\left. r^{i-1}_0 < r \leq r^{i}_0 \right| r_1=b\right) \\
&= P\left(\left. r^{i-1}_0 < a\times r_1 + \sqrt{(1-a^2)}\times r_2 \leq r^{i}_0 \right| r_1=b\right) \\
&= P\left(\left. \frac{r^{i-1}_0 - a\times r_1}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} < r_2 \leq \frac{r^{i}_0 - a\times r_1}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} \right| r_1=b\right) \\
&= P\left( \frac{r^{i-1}_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} < r_2 \leq \frac{r^{i}_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} \right) \\
&= P\left( r_2 \leq \frac{r^{i}_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} \right) - P\left( r_2 \leq \frac{r^{i-1}_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}} \right) \\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{r^{i}_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{r^{i-1}_0 - a\times b}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)}}\right)\text{.}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Explaining the problem to someone also helped me in my understanding, and your solution is also able to point out my mistake.